# name of last person who modified node - Display suite

Tags: display-suite

with Display suite in Drupal 7 I can get the last modified date , but how can I display which user did the last modificatioin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to see who did the last revision is to, well, enable revisions for that content type and require them. This won't help you with past edits, but going forward, every edit will create a new revision, which will have a user associated with it, so you can see who made the last edits.

Comment: In the view I get a choice to see revision: updated date, and log message, but not the user who did the last update.  How do I see that in the view?

Comment: answer of how to see it here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178402/how-to-see-node-revision-user-in-a-view