# how to see node revision user in a view

Tags: views, nodes

In drupal 7, I have revisions turned on, and I want to make a view to display the last updated date and the user who last updated it.  The problem is I cannot get a field for "revision user" as an available field to see .    The only revision fields available are the updated date, and log message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create view (content revisions view) like below images:

In view relationships please add  `content revisions : user`  for user information

[image]

[image]

Thanks!